# Padding-left on div move the next div

Tags: html, css

I'm stuck on this little problem, very stupid I know, but I can not find a configuration-css to solve the problem (position relative margin-left, padding-left, none of that works)

problem : add a padding-left to this div - ***sidebar-user-div11***

### css

```
.sidebar-user{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ff7801;
    background: #ff7801;
}

.sidebar-user-div1{
    /*position: relative;*/
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: purple;
}
.sidebar-user-div2{
    /*position: relative;*/
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.sidebar-user-div11{
    /*position: relative;*/
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    /*margin-left: 15px;*/
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.sidebar-user-div12{
    /*position: relative;*/
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

### html

```
<div class="sidebar-user">
    <div class="sidebar-user-div1">
        <div class="sidebar-user-div11">
            Text with padding left :(
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar-user-div12">

        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-user-div2">

    </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nicolomonili/pahy7x24/1/)

Comment: There is 10px padding, so what is the problem?

Comment: the div with background black , should be to the right of the div with red background , try to remove this line padding-left: 10px; from .sidebar-user-div11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding ...

```
box-sizing:border-box;
```

to div11 (http://jsfiddle.net/pahy7x24/2/)